# angular - Subscribing to Observable returns nothing

Tags: angularjs, typescript, observable

I'm writing unit tests for a simple service. The service gets a list of users from the backend REST API.

```
// user.service.ts
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';
import {ListDto} from '../../dto/commons/list.dto';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getUserList(): Observable<ListDto> {
    return this.http
      .get<ListDto>(environment.coreUrl + environment.basePath + '/user');
  }
```

In my unit test, I try to log the `Observable` returned by `getUserList()`, but there doesn't seem to be any output. I can't perform any validations because nothing is returned. Here is my unit test:

```
// user.service.spec.ts
import {UserService} from './user.service';
import {inject, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController} from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe('UserService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [
        UserService
      ]
    });
  });

  afterEach(inject([
    HttpTestingController
  ], (httpMock: HttpTestingController) => {
    httpMock.verify();
  }));

  it('should be able to get the list of users',
    inject(
      [HttpTestingController, UserService],
      (httpMock: HttpTestingController, service: UserService) => {
        service.getUserList().subscribe((data) => {
          console.log(data); // no output
        });
        // sanity
        const req = httpMock.expectOne('http://localhost:8080/v1/api/user');
        expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
      }
    )
  );
```

I'm quite new to Angular, so I must be wrong somewhere. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course nothing is returned, since you didn't tell the mock Http Client to return anything.

You need to call `req.flush(someTestData)` for that to happen, as explained and shown in [the guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#expecting-and-answering-requests).